# Get Position from WM_LBUTTONDOWN SendMessage

Tags: vb.net, sendmessage, wndproc

I would like to get the x, y position from the Params when the WM_LBUTTONDOWN is sent in vb.net.

I got this to make the param but how do I get the position from it.

```
IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)((y << 16) | x);
```

My function:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
  Select Case m.Msg
    Case WM_LBUTTONDOWN

      'Get the X, Y from m.lparam

    Case Else
      MyBase.WndProc(m)
  End Select
End Sub
```

Update: I just tried this and it works perfectly.

```
Dim pos As New System.Drawing.Point(CInt(m.LParam))
```

Comment: Very nice of the .net people to provide that helpful Int32 constructor for `Point`. You should write it up as an answer rather than editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this and it works perfectly.

```
Dim pos As New System.Drawing.Point(CInt(m.LParam))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = &H201 Then
        Dim pos As New Point(m.LParam.ToInt32())
        '--- etc...
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Comment: So you can do VB too! Only 870 to go now. +1

Answer (score 0):

When the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message is received the xpos = LOWORD(lParam) and yPos = HIWORD(lParam).

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/code/341269